# How to iterate over a map to get all the values for 2 keys

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, iterator

I have read csv and stored the values in map (key-value format)
I need to fetch all values for 2 particular key into an array list to comapre it with database values columns

ArrayList ftlVal = new ArrayList<>();

```
                for (Map<String, String> map : finResult) {
                      Object[] key = {"Column2", "Column6"};
                      for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
                             do {
                                   //for (int j = 0; j <key.length; j++) {
                                          //while (map.get(key[j]) != null) {
                                                Object value = map.get(key[i]);
                                                // System.out.println(value);

                                                if (!ftlVal.contains(value)) {
                                                       ftlVal.add((String) value);
                                                       System.out.println(ftlVal);
                                                       i++;
                                                }
                                          }while (map.containsKey(key[i]));
                                   }
                             }
                             // System.out.println(finResult);
                      //}
                //}
```

I need all the values for column2 and column6 in an arrylist and then to compare those columns with database column2 and column6

Comment: The Map can contain only unique keys. if you try to put duplicate key then it will replace the old value if the key exists. If you want all then your Map should be Map<String,List> and you should add the values in key. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping aside how you compare the ArrayLists with the database columns, the following code will give you the two ArrayLists that you need.

```
ArrayList<String> column2List = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> column6List = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map<String, String> map : finResult) {
  String column2Value = map.get("Column2", null);
  String column6Value = map.get("Column6", null);
  column2List.add(column2Value);
  column6List.add(column6Value);
}
```

The **column2List** and **column6List** are the two ArrayLists that you need.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. Can you please help me with getting distinct values from these arraylist resp?

Comment: If you want unique values you might want to use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList. Perhaps a TreeSet would help if you need the values in a sorted order.